# Apache 301 bulk redirect

Tags: apache, redirect

Is there a way to redirect all link with certain path? For example:

```
mydomain.com/free-products/product1
mydomain.com/free-products/product2
mydomain.com/free-products/productn
```

become:

```
mydomain.com/free/product1
mydomain.com/free/product2
mydomain.com/free/productn
```

I prefer to redirect using apache vhost instead of htaccess

Thanks for the clues..
Appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^free-products/product([0-9]+)$ /free/product$1 [R=301,L]
```

There is no matter where to place it, inside vhost or htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use RedirectMatch.

RedirectMatch permanent ^/free-products/(.*) mydomain.com/free/$1

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html for more information regarding mod_alias.